# How to save all defined variables to file, and recreate them in a new script?

Tags: php, serialization

I want to define PHP variables in one script, and extract them in a sencond script later.

I think the best way to achieve this, is to use serialize and unserialize.

```
$all_vars = serialize(get_defined_vars());
file_put_contents('vars.txt', $all_vars);
unset($all_vars);

$all_vars = unserialize(file_get_contents('vars.txt', true));

foreach ($all_vars as $key => $value) {
   $$key = $value;
}
unset($all_vars);

$all_vars = serialize(get_defined_vars());
file_put_contents('vars2.txt', $all_vars);
```

I would exspect that I have 2 textfiles (vars.txt and vars2.txt) with the exact same content, but they are slightly different.

For example:

vars.txt:

```
"value_a";r:537;s:10:"key_a";i:1090986352011110587;s:7:"counter"
```

vars2.txt:

```
"value_a";a:1:{i:1090986352011110587;r:538;}s:10:"key_a";i:1090986352011110587;s:7:"counter"
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is this the right way to save all defined variables to file, and recreate them in a new script, and why are there differences in the 2 textfiles?

Comment: I would have thought a session was more applicable as even if you get this working, the data will be shared by all calls to the script.

Comment: Obviously the value for `$key_a` changed while you were running that code.

Comment: And the first line shows `r:537` which is recursion.  Use `json_encode/decode`.  More portable.  Also, `get_defined_vars()` gets LOTS more stuff https://3v4l.org/IIm9n and global scope vars will be recursion of the `$GLOBALS` superglobal.

Comment: @miken32 You can see my code in the example, nothing was changed between the 2 text files.

AbraCadaver can you provide me an example how to save all my variables, and load them later with json_encode/decode?

NigelRen I could store the serialized string of my variables in a session, instead of a text file, but the difference between the serialized and unserialized variables would be still there. It is okay, that tha data will be shared by all calls to the script.

Comment: I get identical output as long as I also unset `$key` and `$value` after the loop.

Comment: like @AbraCadaver suggested, `json_encode` your data, then store it in a (best to save in a `.json` file for conformity), then `json_decode` the data from the file when you need it.